# Change to fixed nav after scroll point, but first div is using height: 100vh

Tags: jquery, navigation, singlepage

I have a one page scroller (something similar but a bit simpler than this: http://chriswojcik.net/demos/single-page-nav/) divided into . The current navigation is fixed at the top.

I am trying to...

- put the nav in the top of the second section.
- change nav to fixed when the top of page hits the nav

My problem is that my first section is using height:100vh.

I would normally just use JQuery to change it to fixed at a certain pixel position, but the VH is throwing me off.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I used [this](http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/) script and modified it a bit.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".topnav").css("top", Math.max(0, $(window).height() - $(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

I modified the fiddle into [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jmagnez/a08rch3L/), which only works in jQuery 1.11+